# "<ul> is not allowed as a child of element <ol> in this context"

Tags: css, html, tags, html-lists

I'm trying to make an unordered-and-ordered mix lists exactly as the following example:
[image]

The validator gives me this error:

> **error: Element “ul” not allowed as child of element “ol” in this context.**

here is my code:

```css
ol.numberlist{
   list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul.sqaredotlist{
    list-style-type:square;
}

ol.romanlist{
    list-style-type:lower-roman;
}
```

```html
       <ol class="numberlist">
            <li>An numbered list</li>
            <li>Containing</li>
               
                <ul class="sqaredotlist">
                    <li>A dotted list</li>
                    <li>Containing</li>
                        
                        <ol class="romanlist">
                            <li>A roman numeral list</li>
                            <li>And some items</li>
                            <li>Like this</li>
                        </ol>
                
                    <li>And some items</li>
                    <li>Like this</li>
               </ul>
            
            <li>And some items</li>
            <li>Like this</li>
        </ol>
```

It actually works on the browser, but I want to figure out the way to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Yinhao

Comment: move it to the previous li

Comment: eg: `<li>Containing
                        
                        <ol class="romanlist">
                            <li>A roman numeral list</li>
                            <li>And some items</li>
                            <li>Like this</li>
                        </ol>
                </li>
                    <li>And some items</li>`

Comment: Let me try, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your sub, list needs to be nested in the li you want it to be a child of

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ul` as a direct child of `ol` and vice-versa since the [permitted element is zero or more `li`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/ul.html#ul-content-model). To make it valid either you have to create a new li(*this will assign new number or icon*) or append with the previous `li` element(*this won't break your current style*).

```css
ol.numberlist {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul.sqaredotlist {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol.romanlist {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numberlist">
  <li>An numbered list</li>
  <li>Containing

    <ul class="sqaredotlist">
      <li>A dotted list</li>
      <li>Containing

        <ol class="romanlist">
          <li>A roman numeral list</li>
          <li>And some items</li>
          <li>Like this</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>And some items</li>
      <li>Like this</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>And some items</li>
  <li>Like this</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
ol.numberlist {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul.sqaredotlist {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol.romanlist {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

.none {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numberlist">
  <li>An numbered list</li>
  <li>Containing</li>
  <li class="none">
    <ul class="sqaredotlist">
      <li>A dotted list</li>
      <li>Containing</li>
      <li class="none">
        <ol class="romanlist">
          <li>A roman numeral list</li>
          <li>And some items</li>
          <li>Like this</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>And some items</li>
      <li>Like this</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>And some items</li>
  <li>Like this</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I've fix the code in Pranav's way. Anyway thanks Vikas.